# Limits to setting HTML via JavaScript and Page Methods?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET and C# page that uses some client-side page methods like:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function showDetails(layerName, transDate) {
        PageMethods.GetTransactionDetails(transDate, function (result) {
            $(layerName).html(result);
        });
```

Generally speaking, this code works just fine and pulls back a list of transactions (formatted in HTML) and displays it accordingly.

However, this code does not display anything on days when there's a lot of data. Some data sets may only be something like 30 rows and that displays just fine. But when I have something like 120 rows, that does not display at all.

So I'm guessing that I'm hitting some sort of limit with HTML display. Are there limits associated with any of the code above that I am using? Any thoughts on why it wouldn't display anything at all?

Comment: The html method may have problems with broken HTML. Can you validate the returned HTML manually?

Comment: What is the size of response in dev tools / fiddler?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I have validated the HTML manually. I have also sent other, truncated, datasets to this and it worked just fine. It's only the longer data sets that give trouble

Comment: There is no built-in limit to what can be displayed via HTML, and only 120 rows is well within range of memory limits on systems these days. Don't know if you showed us all the code, but what you've displayed is not correct, in that the function `showDetails` is not closed, but perhaps there's code in the fuction after that which is shown.

Comment: @abhitalks the size varies but an example dataset that I know fails is about 64KB

Comment: I asked that to confirm if you hitting the limit of 4 MB. [(Ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you try increasing the limit in your web.config?

Comment: @abhitalks No, I have not made any changes to my config at all, that's a good point. I'll look at that link and see where it leads.

Comment: `<system.web.extensions><scripting><webServices><jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="arbitrary high value" /></webServices>...`

Comment: @abhitalks After reading the article it sounds like this only applies to JSON. Note that I am passing back straight HTML to the page method

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @JonathanM No errors at all and thats whats perplexing. It literally just does not display for whatever reason

Comment: On a side note, regardless of whether there is a programmatic issue with displaying 120 rows, as a user I wouldn't be very impressed with being faced with 120 rows of non-paginated data...

Comment: @abhitalks your solution was correct. If you want to post it as an answer here I'll mark it as such. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JimBeam: thanks. added as an answer. and yes, even if it is a string, it goes thru the json serializer. try returning an object to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are hitting the maximum length of JSON strings that are accepted by the internal json serializer (the JavaScriptSerializer class). The default value is 4 MB (2097152 characters). Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You may override this in your `web.config` and set it to a higher value:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5242880" /> <!-- 10 MB Approx -->
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

<sub>Footnote: Returning such a huge chunk of data to the client may not be a good idea.</sub>